# Python: Changing an Element in JSON

Tags: python, json, for-loop, element

I'm trying to iterate over a list of JSON "Cards" and update the description of the one with id 1. Seems pretty simple and i'm not sure where i'm going wrong. Code:

```
data = json.load(f)
newData = "This is the correct data"
for aCard in data['theList']:
    if aCard["id"] == 1:
        print("Found id1") #works
        description = aCard["sections"][0]["payload"][0]["description"]
        print(description) #works
        aCard["sections"][0]["payload"][0]["description"] = newData
        print(description) #prints the same wrong data
```

Where am I going wrong here? It's as if this line `aCard["sections"][0]["payload"][0]["description"] = newData` is being completely ignored or i'm doing something incorrectly.

Thanks!

Comment: `aCard["sections"][0]["payload"][0]["description"]` is pointing to `newData` in memory, so you have to reassign `description` because it is referencing the old piece of memory

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not being ignored, but you're not printing the new contents of the cell.  Consider the following code:

```
a = "quick brown fox"
b = a
a = "lazy dog's back"
print(b)
```

What do you expect to see?  What I expect to see is "quick brown fox".  When I changed the value of `a`, that didn't do anything to the string that `b` is bound to.

That's exactly what you're seeing above.  `description` doesn't POINT to that cell.  It refers to the string that started out in the cell.  When you change the value of the cell, it is now bound to a new string, but `description` is still bound to the old string.

Just `print(aCard["sections"][0]["payload"][0]["description"])` and you'll see it's fine.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your response. The print statements I just added really quickly in here, but the actual JSON isn't being updated

Comment: Well, `aCard` is certainly being updated.  The JSON won't be updated until you write it back out with `json.dump(data, f)`, assuming `f` is freshly opened with write permission.  You didn't show us any of that code.

Comment: That makes sense. How would I go about opening the file with write permissions?

Comment: Well, somewhere you have `f = open("jsonfile.json","r")`.  Just do that again with "w".